# finding a magento layout file

Tags: layout, magento, configuration

If I see on a magento page (using the Template Path Hints) that some template is using some block (which is not the default block for that template). 
Is there a way to find which layout file is responsible for this layout change? 
(assuming that the change IS coming from a file and not by direct manipulation of the layout by code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a global search for the block type that is being used.  So, if you expected the block to be **catalog/product_view** and it was instead **whoabob/wheres_theblock**, you could just search for **whoabob/wheres_theblock** to find which module is changing things.

Keep in mind, it may be happening in a layout XML file OR as a rewrite in a module config.xml

Answer (score 0):

In your IDE search the phtml file in layout directory. may you find more, but it allows you to identify and then tries to remove the layout to see if the page still shows whether or not then it's good if it is not the right